# Run out of Gas when trying to create contract

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, remix

I am trying to create a contract that has an instance of two other contracts. I am unable to create it. It keeps running out of gas even if I increase it to 999999999999999999999999999.

If I comment the functions that call functions in the other two contracts, it gets created, otherwise it doesn't.

Is there a way around it? How do contracts that use other contracts get created??

Comment: Could you add the code perhaps?

Comment: Sounds like you have large contracts or you are doing a lot of processing in the constructor.

Comment: Another possibility is some of the child contracts throws an exception, this consumes all available gas so it doesn matter how much you assign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are attempting to create this on a private blockchain. The maximum gas allowed per block is 5.4m. You might be running into this limit.

Comment: I am using Remix while testing .. is it related in any way?

Comment: I don't know. Could you try commenting out only one of the calls to the other contract and then check what the consumed gas for that call is? I would also like to know how much gas you consume when you do not call any other contract.

Comment: Without a call to any contract:  transaction cost  1765920 gas 
 execution cost  1306380 gas, If I keep only a call to one of the contracts  it works with 2 functions and the gas is transaction cost  3843570 gas 
 execution cost  2884534 gas  if for both contracts it does not.

Comment: With those numbers, it looks to me like you are exceeding the block limit for gas when calling both contracts. As I mentioned above, the limit is 5.4 million gas. You probably need to rewrite the contract such that it uses less gas. I don't think there exists another solution. 

Writing to storage (the permanent memory of a contract) is very expensive. If you can reduce the amount of times that you write to storage and reduce the data that you need to store permanently, you might be able to get your contract to work

Comment: do u mean by permanent memory of a contract .. when i create variables? what is the difference between writing to storage and data stored permanently

Comment: By permanent storage, I mean fields and dictionaries in a contract -- the variables that have scope of a contract. Local variables within a method are not stored in storage. Writing to storage and data stored is the same thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76432/discussion-between-haya-raed-and-thorkil-vaerge).